# How did Dominika know the outcome when she initiated her plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-sparrow

Dominika frames her uncle Evan as a the mole in Red Sparrow. I get it that she did all that as she was angry with her uncle.

What I don't get is:

She didn't know the name of the actual traitor till the end of the movie, nor the reason behind it. Yet she opened a new account under her uncle's name and transferred the money to that account, giving fake dvds to the govt framing as if her uncle had supplied those.

All these suggest that she planned to frame her uncle way before anything, maybe when she was given her mission.

Why would she take this risk?
She was not certain if she could know the identity of the real mole. **If the mole didn't reveal himself and she went on framing her uncle**, at least the mole would know that she played falsely and wouldn't that be dangerous for her later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the mole didn't reveal himself and she went on framing her uncle, at least the mole would know that she played falsely and wouldn't that be dangerous for her later?

Certainly it was her long-range plan to **discredit** her uncle, that much is clear.

She went to a lot of trouble to open accounts in his name and use easily traceable encryption of the supposed intelligence from the DOD.

...but at this stage...whether he was the mole wasn't really relevant, she's just out for revenge. The fact that he could be fitted for the role of the mole is just fortunate for her.

As for not knowing who the mole *actually* is...it doesn't really factor into her thinking.

Regardless, what danger is the mole to her? She's already a double agent and the mole can hardly go to the head of Russian Intelligence and say *"I know that her uncle wasn't the mole because I am"*.

If anything her actions would make the mole **more protective** of her, which, as it happens is precisely what happens when he brings her into his confidence.

Comment: Also I was thinking, did Evan purposefully frame Constantine and his lover or was that a planned accident ? Or, is it at all possible to draw  such conclusions ?